# Detecting node is a folder with dynatree

Tags: jquery, nodes, dynatree

How do you detect if a clicked node is a folder ?

I wish to find out if a clicked node is a folder to modify right-click behaviour (if not folder => do something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a node, you can test for `node.data.isFolder`.

In Dynatree event handler this is straightforward:

For example

```
onClick: function(node, event) {
    if(node.getEventTargetType(event) === "title" && node.data.isFolder){
        [...] // Handle the click event
        return false;// Prevent default processing
    }
}
```

From inside a custom handler you might first have to find the node from the target element:

```
var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(el)
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. What I'm trying to do is get the custom `node.data.type` to load a menu via ajax. I'm using [joewalnes's](https://github.com/joewalnes/jquery-simple-context-menu) alternative contextual menu and have been tweaking it so it reacts similarly the browser one. At the moment I'm using a `mouseenter` selector to activate a node so the type can be easily retrieved. If you know of a better way please let me know :) .

Comment: Also, I assume you are the author of dynatree. If anyone has problems getting a hover selector to trigger, a workaround is to use delegate `$("#tree").delegate("a", "mouseenter" //...`. This is how I'm activating a node when the mouse is over it. It seems the dynamically generated elements aren't getting picked up by an `on(` or I'm doing things wrong.

Comment: Personally I think that activating a node on hover is uncommon (you would not expect that in the windows file explorer's tree view, for example). I would suggest to use ` $.ui.dynatree.getNode(event)` when you open the menu. You could also call node.activate() then

Comment: You should always use delegate (or the delgation syntax of `on`) with dynatree nodes, since the DOM nodes are rendered on demand, and might not yet exist when you bind. It is also much more efficient if you have a large number of nodes.